# How to print BIOHAZARD SIGN on console in c#

Tags: c#, unicode

How to print '\u2623' on console in c#. I tried with `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`. But it does not work. When I write `Console.WriteLine("\u2623");` my output is ?(question mark)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("\u2623");` works for me. What have you tried?

Comment: When I write Console.WriteLine("\u2623"); my output is ?(question mark)

Comment: Are you running the application from Visual Studio? Any specific language settings?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 ultimate. Without specific language settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```

It's also possible that your choice of Console font does not support that particular character. Click on the Windows Toolbar Menu (icon like C:.) and select Properties -> Font. Try some other fonts to see if they display your character properly

Comment: Still not working. I have only Consolas and Lucida Console font.

Comment: Well on trying changing the font if its still not visible then the unicode wont be currently visible with the current installed fonts. You would need to install and add that font as a resource when you build your package.

Comment: what is the font of your console?

Comment: Much better you can choose the one that you want from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2623/fontsupport.htm